# how to show and hide UISplitViewController with animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

The current `rootViewController` of window in my app is `MainViewController`. and there's a button in another view controller called `SubViewController`,  I want to show `UISplitViewController` if a user click the button. I have implemented it as following:

```
//SubViewController.m
UISplitViewController *splitVC =[self splitVC];
self.view.window.rootViewController = splitVC;
```

there's no animation to show `splitVC`, I need to show it with slide style, example, to slide the `SubViewController`.view to right to show the `UISplitViewController`, and if the user click a button on `UISplitViewController`, to slide back the `SubViewController.view`

Comment: Rather than using a SplitViewController, have you looked into the SideBar Navigation projects thats out there? (think of the facebook sidebar menu that appears when you swipe, or hit the button).  Check them out: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mfsidemenu

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UISplitViewController *splitVC =[self splitVC];

[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
                  duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = splitVC;
                }
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                }];
```

You can specify different animation types with the `options` parameter