# Navigating to and from a Split View controller

Tags: ios, ipad

The navigation model I am trying to achieve for my app is the user enters a text and searches and I want to navigate to a split view controller with summary results in the left (master view) of the split view and tapping on it reveal a more detailed info. for that in the right side (detail view) and any interaction/clicks there should navigate out to a hosted webView that can display the web source. 
How do I achieve this? I am getting error Split View cannot be pushed from a navigation controller.

FYI: I am newbie to ios/objective-C programming and not familiar if there is an easy way to achieve this.. any feedback/pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the split view controller have to be the root of your app. You cannot push it in a `UINavigationController`. Whenever you want the split view to appear/disappear, you should change the `rootViewController` (in the `AppDelegate`).

However, in your case I suggest you keep the `SplitViewController` on the screen all the time, and do the search in the master controller. Use a `UITableViewController` in it. You can add a search bar to your table, and narrow the results as you type characters in the search bar. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the response!. Two follows 1) can u show an ex. of how to change the rootView controller in AppDelegate and 2) Is the navigation away from Split view allowed (i.e. when I click on something in the detailed view i want to navigate to a webview and in my example using the normal push segue event that seems to be failing.

Comment: 1) check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336019/how-to-show-and-hide-uisplitviewcontroller-with-animation/17336256. 2) you should not place the `UISplitViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`, therefore you can not push it. If you want to show another `UIViewController` from the split, you should present it modally.

Answer (score 13):

UISplitViewController doesn't have to be the root of your app.
You can't push to UISplitViewController but you can navigate it with "Present Modally"

[image]